# fwrite() doesn't write anything

Tags: c

I recently learned how to use fwrite on the Web and tried it on my own, but it does nothing on the file
The file is created, but it is nothing in it.
I tried in line 9 writing as `char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d'};`, `char buffer[4]={'r','e','a','d'};`, `char* buffer="read"`.
What am I doing wrong?
(I also tried `fprintf`, but result was same.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen_s(&fp, "C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\test.txt", "w");

    int buffer[] = { 'r','e','a','d' };

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, &fp);

    fclose(&fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `char buffer[] = ....`. With `int buffer[] = ...` the content of the text file will not be what you expect. See also the answer below which covers another problem

Comment: You should have got many warnings while compiling this code. What compiler do you use and how do you compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the file pointer `fp`, not the pointer to the file pointer `&fp` to [`fwrite()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html) and [`fclose()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html).

Also assigning the return value of [`fopen_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-160) to `fp` is wrong because it is not a file pointer but a value the represents if it was successful.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, "C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\test.txt", "w") != 0)
    {
        fputs("file open error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    int buffer[] = { 'r','e','a','d' };

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another issue is with `fp = fopen_s(&fp,`. `fopen_s` takes the `FILE *` as the first argument and returns `errno`. Assigning to `fp` will make it NULL if fopen_s succeeds

Comment: @JesseBakker Thank you, but I began editing before seeing your comment.

Comment: @MikeCAT it should also be `char buffer[] = ...`

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);` - I think arguments 2 and 3 are wrong, in multiple ways.

Comment: @ryyker Why do you think so?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), fp);`  per: [fwrite()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) (there positions appear to be transposed.  And unless you change `int buffer[] = { 'r','e','a','d' };` to `char buffer[] = { 'r','e','a','d' };`, sizeof(int) should replace `1`.)

Comment: @ryyker I don't think this is wrong because this mean to write one entire `buffer` (one element (from 3rd argument) of size `sizeof(buffer)` (from 2nd argument)). Also changing your `sizeof(int)` to `1` without changing `int buffer[]` to `char buffer[]` looks bad because it will have the output contain only `r` (and 3 `\0`, if `int` is 4-byte long) instead of containing all specified 4 data.

Comment: @ryyker Ah, maybe `&buffer` should be used instead of `buffer` as the 1st argument to match this?

Comment: @ryyker I think `sizeof(*buffer)` (or `sizeof(buffer[0])`) should be better instead of `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: I am not sure what OP intent is, just that it is certainly not an idiomatic choice of usage for `fwrite()`.  The output I get for `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), fp);` is `7200 0000 6500 0000 6100 0000 6400 0000`.  For `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);` is `7200 0000 6500 0000 6100 0000 6400 0000`.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem of seeing output in your files is address in the accepted answer.  This will address the content that is output to your file.

> *"I tried in line 9 writing as char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d'};, char buffer[4]={'r','e','a','d'};, char* buffer="read"*

But then in your post you have the following:

```
int buffer[] = { 'r','e','a','d' };
...
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp); //results in file are: 7200 0000 6500 0000 6100 0000 6400 0000
```

Important to note, `int buffer[] = { 'r','e','a','d' };` does not produce a `C` string.

All of the following are legal arrays in `C`, but only the bottom 2 are treatable as a `C` string, as it is the only one that has the null terminator.

```
int buffer[] = { 'r','e','a','d' };//int array, ASCII values will be output.
char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d'};//char array, not C string
char buffer[4]={'r','e','a','d'};//char array, not C string
char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d','\0'};//C string (editable)
char* buffer="read";//C string (not editable)
```

So, if you just happened to be looking for something like `"read"` to be written to the file rather than `7200 0000 6500 0000 6100 0000 6400 0000` use the following in your code:

```
char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d','\0'};//note the null terminator to avoid UB
...
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);  // results are: "read"
```

Comment: The `'\0'` (and not `'/0'`) at the end is not necessary for the `fwrite`. And your code writes the `\0` to the text file which is probably not what he wants.

Comment: But with the `'\0'` at the end of the array, the `'\0'` will be at the end of the text file which is probably  not wanted, you should point that out or change the code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - /0 is a typo. I have edited. `char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d','\0'};` is identical to `char buffer[] = {"read"};, they are _both_ null terminated char arrays, and the call to `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);` will have identical results using either initialization method.  i.e. both will write text to a text file.  I do not understand your concern (beyond the typo)

Comment: With `char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d','\0'}; fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);` __5 bytes__ are written, the last one being the 0. With `char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d'}; fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);` __4 bytes__ are written.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - LOL, well, yes.  You are correct, no argument there.  `sizeof(buffer)` for the first is 5, and sizeof(buffer)` for the second is 4.  Both will work just fine.  In my previous comment I was saying something a little different:  `char buffer[] = {"read"};` and `char buffer[]={'r','e','a','d','\0'};` both produce  `"read"` and both evaluations of `sizeof(buffer)` will be `5`.